# Error(urlopen) while downloading data from python shell (nltk)

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

I have tried:

1. Changing server index
2. Updating proxy
3. Re-installing python and nltk
4. Downloading numpy ( It was installed properly but threw an exception on cleaning)

   I want to download a stopword list. If this doesn't workout, I will really appreciate if you can suggest me a way to do the same by downloading zip files and physically storing them in the folder or any other method. Thank you!

Here are the error snippets:
1.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4]enter code here on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import nltk
>>>     nltk.download('all')
[nltk_data] Error loading all:
        < urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection
[nltk_data]     refused>
False
>>>
```

2.

```
>>> nltk.download()
Downloader> l
Packages:
Error connecting to server: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the nltk's instructions for [downloading via a proxy server](http://www.nltk.org/data.html#installing-via-a-proxy-web-server)?

If that doesn't work somehow, you can always download what you need on a computer that's not behind a proxy, then copy the whole `nltk_data` folder to a suitable location on the intended computer.

Comment: Hey, thank you. My issue is resolved. I had not given root access to it.

Answer (score 0):

insted of using

```
nltk.download()
```

try using

```
nltk.download_gui()
```

it worked for me